# AWS SNS for IOS8

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Since the release of IOS8 anyone using IOS8 does not receive my notifications. Anyone using IOS 7x continues to receive them without issue.

I am using AWS SNS to send out the notifications and my code that does the work looks like:

```
$snsmessage = $sns->publish(
array(
'TargetArn' => $endpoint,
'MessageStructure' => 'json',
'Message' => json_encode(array(
    'APNS' => json_encode(array(
        'aps' => array(
            'alert' => "message goes here",
            'badge'=>1, 
            'sound'=>'default'
        )
    ))

))
)

);
```

Has the structure changed IOS 8? what do I need to change in order to get them to work in both ios8 and ios7?

Comment: You might have better luck contacting Amazon support more directly - Looks like this issue is on the AWS forums as well: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=571264

Answer (score 0):

Hey Charlie have your team updated their code on the iOS side?

I am currently working on my app to work with SNS in iOS8 and a they way we register for notifications slightly changed.

Also, the AWS SDKv2.0.8 changed the way the app creates endPoints in SNS. I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Hopes my answer helps you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check would be Feedback Service.

Typically each application install happens to receive a device_token from Apple, which you would register with SNS as well in order to send notifications to the device. At times, Apple can update the device_tokens for an already installed apps on a device. In order to know of such updates or invalidated device_tokens, you need to listen to the [APNS Feedback service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html). Then based on the invalid tokens, you would need to reregister the new device tokens with SNS, so you can send the push notifications again.